# ‘PRIMARY’ filegroup is full. How do I increase temdb size in SQL Server Express 2017?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-express

When I reindex a particular table

```
DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName, '',90)
```

I get an error

> Level 17, State 2, Procedure aareindex, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Could not allocate space for object ‘dbo.SORT temporary run storage:
>   422738479742976’ in database ‘mydatabase’ because the ‘PRIMARY’
>   filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files,
>   dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the
>   filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
>   filegroup.

So I want to try increasing the size of TempDb

I can see the size using SSMS by looking at the database properties but I don't see how to set it.

[Update]

```
select type_desc, name, size, max_size, growth from tempdb.sys.database_files
```

returns

[image: these results]

The file size is already 10236 Mb and the Express limit is 10 Gig
However the Disk Usage report shows that 26% of the diskspace is unallocated, 40% is data and 32% is index.

Comment: What does this `select type_desc, name, size, max_size, growth from tempdb.sys.database_files` output?

Comment: Thans @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I updated the question.

Comment: >>>The file size is already 10236 Mb<<< The tempdb data size in your picture is 71Mb only, it's reported in pages and not in Mb, 10Gb is what you see under max_size (1310720 pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The file size is already 10236 Mb and the Express limit is 10 Gig

If your user database `data file size` reached it's limit (10Gb in Express Edition)
but 26% of the diskspace is unallocated, you can try to `rebuild` your indexes with `sort` in `tempdb`.

`DBCC DBREINDEX` is `deprecated` and there is no reason to use in `SQL Server 2017`, and with `alter index..rebuild` you can indicate that you want to perform `sort` in `tempdb`:

```
alter index your_index on your_table rebuild
with (sort_in_tempdb = on, fillfactor = 90);
```

When you `rebuild` an index, you first need the `space` to build the copy of your `index` (and this space will be allocated in your `db`) and to build it you also need space to do `sort`, this space can be allocated in `tempd`. In your case the error clearly said that there was no `space` to do `sort` in your db, so maybe you'll resolve your problem if the `sort` will be performed in `tempdb`.

You can read more on that here: [SORT_IN_TEMPDB Option For Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/sort-in-tempdb-option-for-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Also rebuilding the indexes one-by-one, and disabling non-clustered indexes if rebuilding a heap can reduce the space required.

Comment: I don't get the error if I rebuild one index at a time whether I use SORT_IN_TEMPDB or not.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to increase the size of temp db.

> in database ‘mydatabase’ because the ‘PRIMARY’ filegroup is full.

Is telling you it can't write to your primary filegroup is full (c:\path to database\mydatabase.mdf).  Either there is no disk space where the MDF is stored, or the more likely cause is that your Primary Filegroup has no more available room to write into.

You can address this a few different ways

1. Enable autogrowth if not enabled
2. If autogrowth is enabled increase the maximum size by MB's, percentage or unlimited

**In the GUI**

In SSMS:

- right click your database
- select properties
- select files in the database properties window
- On the Autogrowth Max Size select your auto growth options.

[image]
[image]

**SQL Alter statement**

```
use master
go
-- Use one of the statements below

-- this statement will allow for unlimited file growth 
alter database [mydatabase] modify file ( name ='mydatabase', maxsize = UNLIMITED)

-- this statement will allow the database size to 100MB's.
alter database [mydatabase] modify file ( name ='mydatabase', maxsize = 102400KB)
```

Comment: I updated the question to show that the file is already near maximum size but that it has unallocated space.